# Codeigniter: back from user login and ajax conflict

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i’m using ajax to call every specified period (setinterval) a controller that return result, all this works fine but when i'm logged out and i reconnect i'm redirected to uri of ajax call and not to the page where i was befor deconnecting. Any idea to resolve it ?

Codeigniter version: 2.1.4

Comment: Can you paste some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you save URL to page where you need to be redirect after login in your session each time when you redirect user to login page - you need disable saving this URL for ajax requests.

Comment: in core/URI.php we have $uri = $this->_detect_uri() and  _detect_uri() function contains $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  and it returns URL for ajax requests so its considered the request URi instead of page URi